# How to get value of vuetify number type v-text-field in template

Tags: vue.js, vuex, textfield, vuetify.js

I am trying to pass value of v-text-field in function so I can update database but I don't know how because I am using v-for.

Didn't know what to try.
I can't use v-model because it will change on all items in tracker array that I am looping through.

```
<v-card v-for="track in tracker" :key="track.title" min-width="600" tile class="pa-3 mb-2" dark>
          <v-card-title style="background-color: #2f2f2f">
            <h3 class="white--text headline">{{ track.title }}</h3>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-layout row wrap>
              <v-flex xs5>
                <v-text-field min="0" step="1" type="number" label="Season" :value="track.season"></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-flex xs5>
                <v-text-field min="0" step="1" type="number" label="Episode" :value="track.episode"></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-card-actions>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="green darken-3" depressed @click="updateTrack({ title: track.title, season: 2, episode: 2})" class="mr-3">update</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="primary" depressed @click="deleteTrack(track.title)">delete</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
```

On place where it says season: 2 and episode: 2, that is the place where I want to pass values of text-fields.

It is not working. It goes through my method and as result of `.then` it console log me that update was successful. I will provide updateTrack method:

```
updateTrack (payload) {
    db.collection('users').doc(this.userId).collection('tracker').doc(payload.title).update({
       season: payload.season,
       episode: payload.episode
    })
    .then(() => console.log('updated track'))
 }
```

If I change values in method or in template to simple values like 2 it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do is that in v-text-field in `@change` event add next line of code:

```
track.season = $event
```

All I did is that on every change in input event I assign event payload to track.season. All the same I did for episodes:

```
track.episode = $event
```

Text-field looks like this now:

```
<v-text-field min="0" step="1" type="number" label="Season" :value="track.season" @change="track.season = $event"></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply just like you bind the title you can bind the others :

```html
<v-btn color="green darken-3" depressed @click="updateTrack({ title: track.title, season: track.season, episode: track.episode})" class="mr-3">update</v-btn>
```

Comment: It is not working. It goes through my method and as result of `.then` it console log me that update was successful. I will provide updateTrack method:

`updateTrack (payload) {
    db.collection('users').doc(this.userId).collection('tracker').doc(payload.title).update({
       season: payload.season,
       episode: payload.episode
    })
    .then(() => console.log('updated track'))
 }`

If i change values in method or in template to simple values like 2 it works.